# Weird text before error message on node js

Tags: node.js

what causes this weird text which looks like compressed js on node js error logs. I use esm module loader.
[error log on terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfdGf.jpg)

Edit: I should have clarified that I caused the error on purpose. What I ask is the text on top of it. it is in every error log.

Comment: The real error is at the bottom of the log (Syntax error), it looks like you missed an open parenthesis `(`. Also, don't post screenshots because it makes it harder to debug. Always post a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error where you define your hook. You missed the '('. Try this:

```
app.use('/graphql', createeGraphql());
```

Comment: I'm not asking about the error(I caused it on purpose). what I'm asking is the strange text on top of it. it appears on every error message and fills the terminal

Comment: @Raader Probably you console.logged it ?
Man, you need to give some code.

Comment: @Raader, can you give us more details please.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I didn't console log anything it's not any particular code that is causing it. it is just logs this weird text on every error log

Comment: did you use the 'defineProperty()' method?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out [esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) package is the problem. it logs some minified js every time there is an error. I checked its GitHub repo and turns out it isn't maintained anymore so don't use esm. just put this line to your package.json if you want to use es6 import, export syntax.

```
{
  //rest of your package.json
  type:"module"
}
```